# Get a registered Spark Accumulator by name

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there a way of getting a registered Spark Accumulator by name, without passing an actual reference? Desired behavior:

```
val cnt1 = sc.longAccumulator("cnt1")
val cnt2 = something.getAccumulatorByName("cnt1") asInstanceOf[LongAccumulator]
cnt1.add(1)
cnt2.value // returns 1
```

Thanks

Comment: `AccumulatorContext` is private so I don't think so. But if you want an easy access by name, and you don't care about `asInstanceOf`, why not store all accumulators in `Map`?

Comment: That is probably what I will end up doing. It is just strange to me that this is not built-in in Spark. Maybe there is a good reason not to do it this way - then I would like to know about before I run into trouble :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accumulators in Spark are kept in `AccumulatorContext` and there is no way to get them from it. Spark doesn't allow you to do this because accumulators are **not** kept until you stop `SparkContext`. They implemented canonicalizing mappings: accumulators are kept until you have strong reference to it, and as soon as they pass out of scope GC cleans them up (with special finalization process).

The only way to get accumulator by name is to put it into Map.
If you need for example to write accumulator in your `FileFormat` or `RelationProvider` and then read it in driver, just keep static reference to it.
If you read and write accumulators in the same class and you want to get them by name, you most likely need to create custom accumulator with `Map[String, Long]` inside. It is much more profitable in terms of performance.

Comment: am I correct that in order to access accumulators from executors all of them should be initialized before executors distribution. I mean if there are a way to create accumulators on executors during processing and any mechanism of aware about it other executors?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot access accumulators from executors. You can only create accumulator on executor and change its value. Value of your accumulator will be sent to driver and merged with values from other executors. You cannot send its value to other executors. And there is no need to initialize accumulators on the driver before creating them on executors.